# restoring wordpress database from mysql dump

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Is there way to correctly restore a Wordpress database from an older mysqldumb file (.sql)? I can't remember the wordpress version, but it wasn't lower than 3.4.2.

At the moment whenever I try to restore like this:

`mysql -u blogadmin -p new_db < old_db_dump.sql`

I get no error (at least no error is output) and then I get a white first page on my blog.

Answer (score 2):

White first page usually means that there is a php error during rendering of this page. Try to enable php error_reporting (or error logging) and see these error messages. Depending on error messages you can try to fix wp scripts version or apply updates to your db.

Comment: Thanks. I am no php expert. How can this be done? (Blog is not hosted on Wordpress.com.)

Comment: Guide to enabling error logging - http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Configure_Error_Logging